# Using special characters in XML documents

Tags: xml

I would like to know how to use the character `"&#xA;"` (LINE FEED) to separate some information in an attribute. Look the example below:

```
<element attrinfo="info1=109&#xA;info2=108&#xA;info3=107" />
```

I use `SetAttribute()` to set the attribute's text, but when the I save the XML, the information in `attrinfo` looks like that:

```
<element attrinfo="info1=109&amp;#xA;info2=108&amp;#xA;info3=107" />
```

The `"&"` is a special character, so the XML substitutes it by `"&amp;"`

How can I solve this? I saw something about use Entity Reference but I don't understand how to use it.

Here is my code using \n:

```
ls_DadosAdicionais = "volume=1800;peso=78;altura=157"
ll_pos = POS( ls_DadosAdicionais, ";" ) 
DO
    ls_DadosAdicionais = REPLACE( ls_DadosAdicionais, ll_pos, 1, '~n' )
    ll_pos = POS( ls_DadosAdicionais, ";", ll_pos + 1 )
LOOP WHILE ll_pos > 0
lo_exm = io_xml.createElement( "exame")
lo_exm.SetAttribute( "dados_adicionais", ls_DadosAdicionais )
```

Comment: Can you also post the actual output this produces? (And delete the comments that contain the code). If you see actual new lines in the output instead of "&#xA;", then the API you are using has a bug. You may have to use another separator char (why not keep the semi-colons?). BTW... what language is that?

Answer (score 2):

You should save the actual line feed character to the attribute. The escaping is taken care of by the API.

In other words: If you save the string `"&#xA;"`, the API correctly escapes it as `"&amp;#xA;"`, so that you get back the string `"&#xA;"` when you read the data again. Always store the *data* you want to store, never do any manual escaping.

Answer (score 2):

SetAttributes does the entity translation automatically.  Don't substitute the newline manually.  Just include the \n in the string you pass to SetAttribute.  It should get translated to the proper entity when you save.

Comment: I included the \n in the string but didn´t work. When i open the xml in notepad++, i see the newline instead of the string "&#xA;".

Comment: Notepad++ is too awesome to display the entity.  It translates it back.  Open in regular notepad.

Comment: I opened in regular notepad and it is the same. 
Look how it´s appearing:

<exam code="TRIGL" info="volume=1800
peso=78
altura=157"/>

Comment: I opened in regular notepad and it is the same. Look how it´s appearing: 
    <exam code="TRIGL" info="volume=1800 peso=78 altura=157"/>

Comment: sorry, it doesn´t work here, but it´s appearing in a new line each information of INFO´s attribute, not with spaces like is at my last comment.

Comment: ls_DadosAdicionais = "volume=1800;peso=78;altura=157"
ll_pos = POS( ls_DadosAdicionais, ";" ) 
DO
   ls_DadosAdicionais = REPLACE( ls_DadosAdicionais, ll_pos, 1,  '~n' )
   ll_pos = POS( ls_DadosAdicionais, ";", ll_pos + 1 )
LOOP WHILE ll_pos > 0

lo_exm = io_xml.createElement( "exame")
lo_exm.SetAttribute( "dados_adicionais", ls_DadosAdicionais )

Comment: ls_dados_adicionais="volume=1800;peso=78;altura=157"  
ll_pos =

Comment: i´ll try again, one line each time:
ls_DadosAdicionais = "volume=1800;peso=78;altura=157"

Comment: ll_pos = POS( ls_DadosAdicionais, ";" )

Comment: @Thaisa: Can you delete all these comments now that you've posted the code in your question? Thanks. :)

Comment: i already tried, but when i click in the delete button, appears a red box with the message "you cannot vote for this comment", and the comment is not deleted. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: @Thaisa: The delete button is a small gey "x" at the end of your comment (appears on mouseover). The arrow you clicked on is for voting on comments - it even says "vote this as a great comment" in the tool tip ;-).